# Allow specific field to be updatable in graphql model using amplify auth

Tags: api, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a `User`, `Recipe` and the `Ingredients` table here. The process of my app is when the user viewed the Recipe and then clicked the "finish cooking" button, it will update the `totalCooked` field.

What I want to achieve here is to allow the read but deny the users(except the admin) to update all the fields except the `totalCooked` field.

```
type Recipe @model @auth(rules: [
        { allow: private, operations: [read] }
        { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"]}
    ]){
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    totalCooked: Int @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, operations: [update] }]) //Allow the private users to update this field only
    ingredients: [RecipeIngredients] @connection(name: "RecipeIngredient")
}

type User @model @auth(rules: [
        { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, read] }
        { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
    ]){
    id: ID!
    coins: Int
}


type RecipeIngredients @model (queries: null) @auth(rules: [
        { allow: private, operations: [read] }
        { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
    ]){
    id: ID!
    size: String
    description: String
    recipe: Recipe @connection(name: "RecipeIngredient")
    ingredients: Ingredients @connection(name: "IngredientsRecipe")
}


type Ingredients @model @auth(rules: [
        { allow: private, operations: [read] }
        { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
    ]){
    id: ID!
    name: String
    imageURL: String
    recipe: [RecipeIngredients] @connection(name: "IngredientsRecipe")
}
```

Comment: So what's the actual question? What's wrong with your code?